# I'm trying to use Selenium Webdriver to click on an object in a dynamically built tree node where the object is under layers of divs

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

The bottom layer of the HTML looks like what is in the screenshot. I've tried several different methods and none seem to work.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(., 'Policy')]"))

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='x-tree-node-anchor'] and contains span[(text(), 'Policy')]"

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=\"extdd-1\"]/descendant::span[text()='\\VED\\Policy']")).click();
```

The object is buried in `<div>` tree:
[image: buried object in div tree]

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is inside an `iframe` which you **need to switch to** first:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("TreeIFrame");
```